# Can't use bind variable as table name in sql query APEX ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

```
SELECT * FROM :TABLENAME
```

is my query, and Apex isn't letting me run because the app doesn't know the table name. How can I dynamically query using variable as the table name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how:

- create a classic report using a *dummy* SELECT statement, such as `select * from dual`
- create a text item on that page, let's call it P22_TABLE_NAME
- set its "Submit when enter pressed" property to "Yes"
- edit report's source and set the Type to **PL/SQL Function Body returning SQL Query**
- Function body should be `return 'select * from ' || :P22_TABLE_NAME;`
- set "Use generic column names" property to "Yes", because you're using different table names, and all of them (most probably) have different columns
- run the page; as you put different table names into the P22_TABLE_NAME item and press the Enter key, report contents should change

Comment: Is this subject to SQL injection?

Comment: Yes, you should use dbms_assert.sql_object_name, but only after questioning why you're dynamically determining the table in  the first place
http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com.au/2017/08/do-you-really-need-that-sql-to-be.html

Comment: I agree with both of you. Well, this is the simplest way to do that (at least, I think so). The fact that it *can* be done doesn't mean that it *should* be done. I can't remember that I ever needed to do something like that, apart from amusement (such as answering questions on forums) and I have no idea what will it be used for.

Answer (score 0):

You should know what tables the form might need to query. If you have an application item called `TABLE_NAME`, you can union the results together and pick out the right table like this:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from tablex where :TABLE_NAME = 'TABLEX'
union all
select col1, col2, col3 from tabley where :TABLE_NAME = 'TABLEY'
union all
select col1, col2, col3 from tablez where :TABLE_NAME = 'TABLEZ'
```

The benefit of this approach is that the query will be checked for correct syntax and that the tables have the right columns; and this solution is immune from SQL injection attacks.

The downside is that if a new table is added, you have to modify the query. But if you're creating tables on the fly like this then you should consider revising your strategy anyway.